# Problema instalando cordova-plugin-googlemaps para iOS

Tags: ionic, cordova

Estoy instalando `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` para iOS pero nunca se instala.

Ya intente reinstalando cordova, ionic, node y bajando de versiones:

```
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.7.1",
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Amigo, estoy presentando actualmente el mismo problema y nada de lo que comentan en github parece funcionar... has podido resolver?

Comment: Hola Luis RM, ¿cómo estás intentando instalarlo? ¿qué comando usas y cuál es el error que ves en pantalla? Completa el [tour] y lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas y que sean mejor aceptadas por la comunidad. Saludos.